# How to proportinally size the image based on the iphone is using

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, constraints

Let say I have a large image (400wx700h) pixels.
I want this image to be centered on the iphone and take 1/4 of the display area. Doesn't matter if is iphone 4 or iphone 6+, I still want this image to be centered and take only 1/4 of the display area.
Also, I want to design this in storyboard and using constraints, with no coding. I know how to center the image, but not sure about the 1/4 portion. Can someone please guide me?

Thanks
Borna

Answer (score 0):

Create constraints for equal width and height with the super view, and set the multiplier in each constraint to 0.25

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a UIImageView to contain your UIImage.
2. Set the imageView.contentMode to ScaleToFit
   [image]
3. Use the Equals Widths and Equals Heights constraints from the imageView to your viewController's view.
   [image]
4. Use the multiplier (4 with Inverse Multiplier) on the constraints to adjust the size to what you want.
   [image]

Comment: Sorry, but still not clear, Is there an example somewhere that you can share with me?

Comment: Let say now I have 3 images that I want to center. So I can set constraint for equal width and height for all 3 images with the super view and then set the multiplier in each constraint to ?

Comment: Depends how you want the images appear. You can definitely set multiple equal width and height constraints to the superview--if you want to stack them vertically, for example. Use the width/height constraints to manage the size and other constraints to manager their positions.

Comment: I wish I could post a diagram, but don't have enough reputations yet to post picture. 
So here what I want to do. 
1. Have 1 toolbar on top
2. Have 2 tool bars on bottom
3. a view in the middle and in that view I want to have 15 buttons with images 
row1: 1 button centered
row2: 2 buttons centered
row3: 3 buttons centered
row4: 3 buttons centered
row5: 3 buttons centered
row6: 2 buttons centered
row6: 1 button centered
I am having a very very hard time to centered those buttons
of course this should handle all iphone cases.

Comment: For a layout that complex you should consider using a `UICollectionView` with a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`. Use the constraints to control the size and positioning of the collection view, but do all of your intricate layout within the collection view.