# position a view in storyboard at 1/3 of screen size

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint, universal-storyboard

I'm trying to position a view in storyboard to always have it top edge at 1/3 of screen size. I have currently set a constraint to Top Layout Guide, but the constraint's constant is...well it is constant no matter which screen size it is used in, but I want it to be 1/3 of screen size. Can this be done entirely in storyboard? Thanks for answers

Screenshot of current state:

[image]

Comment: YEs this is possible, can you give us a screenshot?

Comment: I added a screenshot, nothing special happening there.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30924523/how-to-proportinally-size-the-image-based-on-the-iphone-is-using/30924813#30924813

Comment: FYI, DanLoughney's linked question adjusts SIZE of a view relative to screen; this question is about POSITION of a view on the screen.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Create a constraint between the view's top edge and the superview's bottom edge. Set the constraint's constant to zero, and set its multiplier to 1:3. Like this:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me, when I set the constant to 0, it hugs the view to the bottom of the screen. Also, I can't seem to create a constraint that goes to "Superview.Bottom", it always creates it to go to "Superview.Bottom Margin"

Answer (score 4):

You can setup it against center or bottom.
Here is an example constraints related to center:
(1/3 from top  = 1.66 from center)
[image: contraints]

Comment: Use a proper rational number for the multiplier like `5:3` :P

Answer (score 4):

For anyone trying to make this work programatically I was not able to handle that by 'anchors' style but old `NSLayoutConstraint` initializer worked:

```
let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: floatingBtn,
                                    attribute: .centerY,
                                    relatedBy: .equal,
                                    toItem: view,
                                    attribute: .bottom,
                                    multiplier: 1/3,
                                    constant: 0)
constraint.isActive = true
```

Credits to [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32101066/2830169).

Answer (score 3):

You can add empty (clear color) UIView, pin it to the top, and set it's height to be equal to 1/3 of the superview. Then you can pin the top of your yellow view to the bottom of your empty UIView.