# How to Set Constraint so that Bottom of UIImage is at 1/5th the Height of the Screen?

Tags: ios, uiimage, storyboard, constraints

I have a background image and I want to anchor a child UIImage so that its bottom is n% of the height of the background. I deleted all the constraints on the child image and created a constraint

```
Child Image.Bottom Equal backgroundImage.Bottom
```

With Constant 0. I was hoping that changing the multiplier to 5 or .2 would move the child UIImage, but the child UIImage doesn't move.

[image]

I tried following the instructions in this post [position a view in storyboard at 1/3 of screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100248/position-a-view-in-storyboard-at-1-3-of-screen-size) but got the same results.

Here is a screenshot that shows what I am trying to do. The yogi image needs to sit on the mat. The bottom of the pose image will always be on the same spot on the map. The mat is baked into the background image.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you want to do? That would help others.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a spacer view at the bottom of the screen that is fixed to 20% of the background view, then align the bottom of your image to the top of that.

In code this would be

```
spacerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.bottomAnchor)
spacerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2)
imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: spacerView.topAnchor)
```

You should be able to make these using the Interface Builder too.

Comment: I tried this but my spacerView ends up going all the way up the screen regardless of multiplier. My spacerView is a UIView that I placed in IB.

Comment: To see how to do it in Interface Builder look at @fyodor's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935825/autolayout-make-height-of-view-relative-to-half-superview-height